# Python Webscraping Dynamic Website with Load more button

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from this site and I am now trying to be able to access the data that is loaded when clicking the "load more" button. I am trying to do this using the beautifulsoup library but haven't found success, any suggestions?
Code so far:

```
from cgitb import html
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 



html_text = requests.get('https://www.ufc.com/athletes/all').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")
fighters = soup.find_all('div', class_ = ("node node--type-athlete node--view-mode-all- 
athletes-result ds-1col clearfix"))

for fighter in fighters:
 fighter_name = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing- 
 athlete__name")).text.replace("_", " ").replace("-", " ")
 fighter_nickname = fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-nickname field-- 
 type-string field--label-hidden"))
 fighter_nickname = fighter_nickname.text if fighter_nickname else None 
 fighter_weight_class = fighter.find('div', class_ = ("field field--name-stats-weight- 
 class field--type-entity-reference field--label-hidden field__items")).text
 fighter_ufc_record = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record")).text
 print(f'''Fighter Name: {fighter_name.strip()}''')
 print("************************")
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML contents are loaded via API as AJAX as POST method. So you have to use API url instead if you wanna extract data from API unlike selenium.

Each page contains 12 items, total 2728/12=228 pages if you want to grab all the pages just replace 51 to 228

**Full working code as an example:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = 'https://www.ufc.com/views/ajax?_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax'

payload = {
    'view_name': 'all_athletes',
    'view_display_id': 'page',
    'view_args':'',
    'view_path': '/athletes/all',
    'view_base_path': '',
    'view_dom_id': 'fb169c31c0649b4e27cd99e1be301223d1cceb233cf56e4330f172815bad254d',
    'pager_element': '0',
    'gender': 'All',
    'page': '1',
    '_drupal_ajax': '1',
    'ajax_page_state[theme]': 'ufc',
    'ajax_page_state[theme_token]':'',
    'ajax_page_state[libraries]': 'addtoany/addtoany,better_exposed_filters/auto_submit,better_exposed_filters/general,classy/base,classy/messages,core/normalize,core/picturefill,facets/drupal.facets.link-widget,facets/drupal.facets.views-ajax,google_analytics/google_analytics,layout_discovery/onecol,poll/drupal.poll-links,system/base,ufc/global-css,ufc/global-js,ufc_facets/search-with-limit,ufc_localization/region,ufc_localization/timezoner,ufc_overlay/ufc_overlay,ufc_search/ufc_search.all_athletes,views/views.ajax,views/views.module,views_infinite_scroll/views-infinite-scroll',
    }
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}


data = []
for payload['page'] in range(1,51):
    req = requests.post(api_url,data=payload,headers=headers)
    #print(req)

    e = req.json()[1]['data']
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e,'lxml')
    #print(soup)

    # with open('aj.html', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    #     f.write(str(soup))

    fighters= soup.select('.item-list > ul > li')
    for fighter in fighters:
        fighter_name = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__name"))
        fighter_name = fighter_name.text.replace("_", " ").replace("-", " ").strip() if fighter_name else None
        fighter_nickname = fighter.select_one('.c-listing-athlete__nickname div div')
        fighter_nickname=fighter_nickname.text if fighter_nickname else None
        fighter_weight_class = fighter.select_one('span[class="c-listing-athlete__title"] > div')
        fighter_weight_class = fighter_weight_class.get_text(strip=True) if fighter_weight_class else None
        fighter_ufc_record = fighter.find('span', class_ = ("c-listing-athlete__record"))
        fighter_ufc_record = fighter_ufc_record.text if fighter_ufc_record else None
        data.append({
            'fighter_name':fighter_name,
            'fighter_nickname':fighter_nickname,
            'fighter_weight_class':fighter_weight_class,
            'fighter_ufc_record':fighter_ufc_record
            })
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        fighter_name fighter_nickname fighter_weight_class fighter_ufc_record
0        John Adajar             None         Welterweight      0-1-0 (W-L-D)
1         Juan Adams     "The Kraken"          Heavyweight      5-3-0 (W-L-D)
2        Scott Adams             None          Heavyweight      6-0-0 (W-L-D)
3      Anthony Adams             None         Middleweight      8-2-0 (W-L-D)
4    Zarrukh Adashev       "The Lion"            Flyweight      4-4-0 (W-L-D)
..               ...              ...                  ...                ...
595     Grant Dawson            "KGD"          Lightweight     18-1-1 (W-L-D)
596       Martin Day    "The Spartan"        Featherweight      8-6-0 (W-L-D)
597             None             None                 None               None
598        Jason Day          "Dooms"         Middleweight     17-7-0 (W-L-D)
599    Angel De Anda      "The Dream"    Light Heavyweight     18-6-0 (W-L-D)

[600 rows x 4 columns]
```